# forbidden in ajax call error function in codeigniter csrf

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, csrf

I'm just getting started with codeigniter I want to insert some data into database via ajax but I have a problem with my ajax call;
I've been searching for two hours but I could not solve the problem.
My problem is when I click on submit button it says forbidden.
Also my csrf protection is set to TRUE! Please help, thanks

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".addbtn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#mname").val()==='' || 
           $('#sname').val() === '' || 
           $('#genre').val()==='' || 
           $('#album').val()==='' ||
           $('#publishyear').val() ==='' ||
           $('#artist').val()==='')
        {
            alert("Please fill all the fields!");
            return false;
        }

        $("#FormSubmit").hide(); 
        $("#LoadingImage").show(); 

        var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
        var data = {
                'mname': $("#mname").val(),
                'sname': $('#sname').val(),
                'genre': $('#genre').val(),
                'album': $('#album').val(),
                'publishyear': $('#publishyear').val(),
                'artist': $('#artist').val(),
                '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':
                '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
                };

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url:  baseurl+"index.php/admin_page/send_ajax", 
        data: data, 
        success:function(){
            alert("success");

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $("#FormSubmit").show(); 
            $("#LoadingImage").hide(); 
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        });
  });});
```

**Config file**

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

**Controller**

```
public function send_ajax(){


    $data = array(
                'name_of_music'=>$this->input->post("mname", TRUE),
                'artist'=>$this->input->post("artist", TRUE),
                'name_of_singer'=>$this->input->post("sname", TRUE),
                'genre'=>$this->input->post("genre", TRUE),
                'album'=>$this->input->post("album", TRUE),
                'publishyear'=>$this->input->post("publishyear", TRUE)
            );
    $json_data['lyrics_info_data'] = json_decode($data);
    $this->user_model->insert_json_in_db($json_data);
  }
```

**Model**

```
public function insert_json_in_db($json_data){
    $this->db->insert('lyrics', $json_data);
  }
```

Comment: you should `json_encode($data)`, not json_decode

Comment: Zeeshan I fixed that but still not working! says forbidden

Comment: Can you make sure if your controller's function is getting called from ajax by just putting `echo 'In controller;exit;`

Comment: yeah I'm sure. Everything is set up correctly! I don't know why still saying forbidden

Comment: I think the problem is csrf configurations  I don't know where!

Comment: So disabling CSRF getting you the result ?

Comment: TRUE or FALSE; nothing won't changed. The different between those is when the CSRF is set to FALSE it says not found instead of forbidden.

Comment: Thats what i am trying to help you debug the issue,so for that you need to do or follow what is suggested...Just let me know if you can see the echo in controller as i suggested above

Comment: no I cant see it. The request rejected `http://[::1]/CodeIgniter/index.php/admin_page/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url();%20?%3Eindex.php/admin_page/send_ajax 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: Its completely clear here from your URL that is not correct.Try to correct and then try again

Comment: Also you should use baseurl in Javascript as `var baseurl = <?php echo base_url() ?>;` and make sure you are getting right base url
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm what is the use of this line `$json_data['lyrics_info_data'] = json_decode($data);` ? I think error is with this line.

You may use `$json_data['lyrics_info_data'] = $data;` instead of `$json_data['lyrics_info_data'] = json_decode($data);`

Also the model function need to update.

```
public function insert_json_in_db($json_data){
    $this->db->insert('lyrics', $json_data['lyrics_info_data']);
}
```

**Script update**

Codeigniter will regenerate its crcf token on each request and this info will be stored in cookie. So token value you need to take from cookie and send along with ajax data you are passing. What I am doing with folliwing javascript is that, using a common function to attach crcf value along with all the ajax request.

In jquery there is an option to add custom data along with ajax request. 
See jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/ for more details

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 

function getCookie(c_name) { // A javascript function to get the cookie value 
    if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if(c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if(c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR){ // This function will attach "csrf_test_name" with all the request you are sending. 
    if (options.type.toLowerCase() === "post") { // Required only if its a post method 
        var csrf_token = getCookie("csrf_test_name");
        // initialize `data` to empty string if it does not exist
        options.data = options.data || "";

        // add leading ampersand if `data` is non-empty
        options.data += options.data?"&":"";

        // add _token entry
        options.data += "csrf_test_name=" + csrf_token;
    }
});
 });
   </script>
```

You can remove `'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'` from `var data`.

Important note: if you change `$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';` in config.php then you need to update this script as well.

Please try after updating your code and let me know if issues still exists.

Comment: still says forbidden.

Comment: Can you ensure that you have loaded your model file?

Comment: I'm 100 percent sure because the other methods in my controller work properly

Comment: yes I tried your code. The problem is ajax can't send the request to the method in my controller at all here is my url: `url:  "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/admin_dashboard/send_ajax",`

Comment: What happens when you directly call your "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/admin_dashboard/send_ajax" in browser ? 

Controller name is "admin_dashboard" and the file name is "Admin_dashboard" (note the first letter of the controller should be capital if you using CI ver 3)?

Comment: nothing happens just an empty page with no errors in console. Yes currently I'm using CI ver 3 and the first letter is capital. I did everything right I updated my code over and over but nothing changed.

Comment: What is the response code you are getting?

just comment all the code inside function "send_ajax" and just echo some string and check anything you are getting.

Comment: I can see the echo and even I can access to the function without using the ajax call it'll work fine.

Comment: hmm then may be issue is with your model. 

1). Make sure that you have loaded the model. 2). if you enabled gzip-compress just make it false for debugging the issue.  Config.php ==> $config['compress_output'] = FALSE;  3). Make sure that you have set environment as "development" then only you will get all errors. 4). Test after disabling csrf config in  "confic.php" $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;

Comment: WOW FINALLY; after two days searching I can't believe it, you just solved my question. Disabling csrf solved the problem. really appreciated. It worked with  $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE. by the way I loaded my model and works fine and compress_output is set to FALSE. Thank you :)))

Comment: Ah thats great!

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you are getting right `base_url()` and in javascript you should define the `base_url()` globally somewhere so that you can access it in any script as below

```
var baseurl = <?php echo base_url() ?>;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You are going way out of your way to make this difficult. csrf is not your problem. Try something like this

```
$(function () {
 "use strict";
 $("#form2").submit(function () {
 var data = $("#form2").serialize();
 //alert(data); return false;
 $.ajax({
  url: "/log/login",
  data: data,
  type: "POST",
  success: function (msg) {
    $("#display").text(msg);
  },
  error: function (msg) {
    $("#display").text("its all bad");
  }
  });
  return false;
 });
 });
```

(Of course you will need to put your own form id in etc)

Your controller should look something like this:

```
  $data = array(
'borncity'  => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('borncity'))),
'state'     => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('state'))),
'country'   => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('country'))),
'family'    => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('family'))),
'year'      => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('year'))),
'state1'    => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('state1'))),
'deathcity' => htmlspecialchars(trim($this->input->post('deathcity')))
);

$this->form_validation->set_rules('borncity', 'city of birth', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'state', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'country', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('family', 'family', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'year', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('state1', 'Born State', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('deathcity', 'Death City', 'trim');

if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  echo validation_errors();
}else
{
  $this->db->insert('cities', $data);
  echo "Success"; //this will show up in your ajax success line
}
}
```

Use Codeigniter's form validation in your controller. You do not need to use json decode. Please note these are examples

Comment: I updated my code like above but not working, still says forbidden! ajax can't send the request to the method I don't know why but it seems can't find the method at all.

Comment: Does it work if you dont use ajax? Remember that the ajax url is the same as the method url

Comment: yes I can use codeigniter form and send my data to the controller. It'll work fine with that way. I tried your above code but the ajax rejected the request again.